# How to concatinate multiple vectors of shared_ptr's?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I've seen other post but I am trying to do this using some of the `<algorithm>` methods. I have a pointer to a map which contains a key to a vector of pointers to BaseElement classes like the following.

```
using ElementV = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BaseElement>>;
using ElementM = std::map<int, ElementV>;
using SElementM = std::shared_ptr<ElementM>;

SElementM elements;
```

What I am trying to do is concatenate each of the vectors (ElementV) stored as values in the map (ElementM) and populate one large ElementV. I'd like to not have to do deep copies and just access the original elements by their smart pointers (shared_ptr(BaseElement)) from the allElems vector.

The following is wrong, but gives the idea of what I'm trying to do.

```
ElementV allElems;

for (auto& index : indices) {
    allElems = elements->at(index);
}
```

I suspect I should be using lambas with std::copy, but have been unable to get something similar to the following to work and I think it's because of iterators.

```
std::copy(allElems.begin(), allElems.end(), [const elements &elems](std::vector<shared_ptr<BaseElement> &val) {
    elems ...?
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: copy only moves into _existing_ elements - try using the [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) to adapt to adapt the end iterator of your destination vector to become an inserter.  Besides that - typically we need more information to help, e.g., compiler error messages, exceptions thrown, whatever, plus full (but minimal) code that can be _run_...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get pairs of keys (first) and values (second) via iteraters of `std::map`, so inserting each vectors via [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) is one way.

```
ElementV allElems;

std::for_each(elements->begin(), elements->end(), [&allElems](const auto& p) {
    allElems.insert(allElems.end(), p.second.begin(), p.second.end());
});
```

Comment: This can be cleaned up a little by using a [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) instead of `std::for_each()`, eg: `for(const auto& p : *elements) { allElems.insert(allElems.end(), p.second.begin(), p.second.end()); }`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
ElementV allElems;

//assuming c++17 compiler
for(auto& [ind, elemVectorPtr]: *elements){ //iterate through index, element-vector pointer pair in elements map 
    //copy across all pointers in element-vector into allElems vector
    std::copy(elemVectorPtr->begin(), elemVectorPtr->end(), std::back_inserter(allElems)); 
}
```

If you don't have a c++17 compiler, just iterate directly through pairs of items in the map:

```
for(auto& pair : *elements){
    std::copy(pair.second->begin(), pair.second->end(), std::back_inserter(allElems));
}
```